# How to save measured pixel distance data in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I got this code from [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imdistline.html)

```
figure, imshow('pout.tif');
h = imdistline(gca);
api = iptgetapi(h);
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imline',...
                              get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));
api.setDragConstraintFcn(fcn);
```

Can you tell me how i can save the pixel distance data measured between two points "dynamically" into a separate file or as a variable in matlab

Answer (score 1):

```
figure, imshow('pout.tif');
h = imdistline(gca);
api = iptgetapi(h);
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imline',...
                              get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));
api.setDragConstraintFcn(fcn);  

dist = api.getDistance()
```

I believe you are looking for how to use the API. In the above example, you call api followed by the functions on the page you listed. I.e.

```
api.getDistance
api.getAngleFromHorizontal
```

etc

Comment: this saves the pixel data but how can i make it dynamic. The above code randomily assigns two point in an image and retrive that distance data.I want pixel distance data between a specific positions in the image

Comment: You should be able to just calculate it manually.
I.e. pythag. theorem.
Load the image as a vector  A = imread('pout.tif')

If you know x1,y1 and x2,y2
dist = sqrt((x2-x2)^2 +(y2-y1)^2)